# FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE Google-managed SSL certificate in Load Balancing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I am working with Load Balancing to have https to my static website and I have my domain in GoDaddy

At the initial stage I only had Http so I painted my domain with cname pointing to      c.storage.googleapis.com with domain name for storage and public its working.

Now to have Https through Load Balancing, I created two Frontend configuration one is Http having static IP and enabled CDN that is point to my cloud storage I can reach my website with the static IP.

With the same configuration I have the second Frontend configuration as Https that points to the same Static IP with Google-managed SSL certificate.

I was expecting the certificate status to go green but I am facing an issue as **FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE** am I missing anything.

Tried multiple times but it fails after 15-20 min

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I fixed it- We need to point the Static IP to DNS in my case I have in GoDaddy, It took some time to point DNS and then it took time for my Google-managed SSL certificate to turn green.

Once it is done I had an issue with `err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch` for this we need to add Policy to tell LB to use TLS 1.2 but in my case it automatically resolved in 10 min.

We can Point DNS in two ways one by directly adding Static IP to A record in GoDaddy other is by creating a Cloud DNS in GCP and point Nameserver in GoDaddy.

Comment: If this fixed your issue, can you mark this answer as accepted for greater visibility in the community? Thanks!

Comment: I'm dealing with that same problem.

Could you please tell me:

    1. How long the Google-managed SSL certificate turn to green from the time we point DNS to static IP of Load Balancer 's GCP?

    2. Which SSL Policy you use? The default one (GCP default) or need to create a new SSL Policy with minimum TLS 1.2?

Tks so much!

Comment: I hope you must be done by the time, It happened instantly for me. I dint make any configuration with TLS 1.2 it worked after turning green.