# How to set DNS records for my domain to reference the IP address of my load balancer also getting FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE in LB Google Cloud Console

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, dns, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I am working with Load Balancing to have https to my static website and I have my domain in GoDaddy

I created a LoadBalancer with

- Backend configuration: To my Cloud storage buckets & enabled CDN.
- Frontend configuration: Https having static IP I have enabled
  **Google-managed SSL certificate** with my domain example.com which is in GoDaddy.

Do I need to do any configuration in GoDaddy like pointing, After 10-20 min I get **FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE** in domain status

I am new and don't know how to link.

In google docs I can see DNS records for your domain must reference the IP address of your load balancer's target proxy, Can someone help me to understand.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates?hl=en_US&_ga=2.190405227.-1195839345.1570257391#certificate-resource-status

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it, We need to point the Static IP to DNS in my case I have in GoDaddy, It took some time to point DNS and then it took time for my Google-managed SSL certificate to turn green.

Once it's done I hade an issue with err_ssl_version_or_cipher_mismatch for this we need to add Policy to tell LB to use TLS 1.2 but in my case it automatically resolved in 10 min.

We can Point DNS in two ways one by directly adding Static IP to A record in GoDaddy other is by creating a Cloud DNS in GCP and point Nameserver in Godaddy.

We must establish a link to confirm our DNS with Static IP of LB so that the SSL turns Green after confirming Domain status.